# radio button not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am beginner.radio button not working properly. I dn't know what is a problem

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Upload our video file";
        RadioButton2.Checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Upload our image file";
        RadioButton1.Checked = false;
    }
}
public void upload()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into video_info(Name,path,user_name,email,comment)values(@Name,@path,@user_name,@email,@comment)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txt_file.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", "video/" + fileuplod.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", use_name.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", comment.Text);
    fileuplod.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/video/" + fileuplod.FileName));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    upload();
}
```

}

What I want to do.I have two radio button.Image and video.Suppose user select image.then all the detail will save on image table or if user click on video.All the detail goes to image_database.

May be my logic is wrong.

Comment: What is "not working properly"? What do you expect to happen and what does happen?

Comment: prob---****both radio button checked*** value not insert into different tables

Comment: thnx guys for help.... *I'm fixed d error ,use group function to group two radio button*

Answer (score 2):

put auto postback to true in radiobutton property

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this 
public void upload(string query)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txt_file.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", "video/" + fileuplod.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", use_name.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", comment.Text);
    fileuplod.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/video/" + fileuplod.FileName));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string query;
if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
    {

       query="insert into video_info(Name,path,user_name,email,comment)values(@Name,@path,@user_name,@email,@comment)";
       Label1.Text = "Upload our video file";
        RadioButton2.Checked = false;
    }
    else
    {

       query="insert into Image_info(Name,path,user_name,email,comment)values(@Name,@path,@user_name,@email,@comment)";
       Label1.Text = "Upload our image file";
        RadioButton1.Checked = false;
    }
  if(query!="")
    {
       upload(query);
    }

}
```

Comment: thnx for help ,But how database know what is  video path and image path.becoz u can-not use image path or file.....showing error on string query(value have not assign)

Comment: for that you have to use fileuploade control.